# How to get difference or delta of counts entries of each days with window functions?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with few fields like id, country, ip, created_at. Then I am trying to get the deltas between total entry of one day and total entry of the next day.

```
CREATE TABLE session (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    country varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ip varchar(255),
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO `session` (`id`, `country`, `ip`, `created_at`) VALUES
  ('1', 'IN', '10.100.102.11', '2021-04-05 20:26:02'),
   ('2', 'IN', '10.100.102.11', '2021-04-05 19:26:02'),
  ('3', 'US', '10.120.102.11', '2021-04-17 10:26:02'),
  ('4', 'US', '10.100.112.11', '2021-04-16 12:26:02'),
  ('5', 'AU', '10.100.102.122', '2021-04-12 19:36:02'),
  ('6', 'AU', '10.100.102.122', '2021-04-12 18:20:02'),
  ('7', 'AU', '10.100.102.122', '2021-04-12 23:26:02'),
  ('8', 'US', '10.100.102.2', '2021-04-16 21:33:01'),
  ('9', 'AU', '10.100.102.122', '2021-04-18 20:46:02'),
  ('10', 'AU', '10.100.102.111', '2021-04-04 13:19:12'),
  ('11', 'US', '10.100.112.11', '2021-04-16 12:26:02'),
  ('12', 'IN', '10.100.102.11', '2021-04-05 15:26:02'),
   ('13', 'IN', '10.100.102.11', '2021-04-05 19:26:02');
```

Now I have written this query to get the delta

```
SELECT T1.date1 as date, IFNULL(T1.cnt1-T2.cnt2, T1.cnt1) as delta from (
  select TA.dateA as date1, MAX(TA.countA) as cnt1 from (
    select DATE(created_at) AS dateA, COUNT(*) AS countA
    FROM   session
    GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
 UNION 
   select DISTINCT DATE(DATE(created_at)+1) AS dateA, 0 AS countA
   FROM session
 ) as TA
  group by TA.dateA
 ) as T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  select DATE(DATE(created_at)+1) AS date2,
        COUNT(*) AS cnt2
 FROM   session
 GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
) as T2
 ON T1.date1=T2.date2
 ORDER BY date;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f5fd26/60
Then I am getting the results as

```
date    delta
2021-04-04  1
2021-04-05  3
2021-04-06  -4
2021-04-12  3
2021-04-13  -3
2021-04-16  3
2021-04-17  -2
2021-04-18  0
2021-04-19  -1
```

Now, is there any place of improvements/optimizes on it with/or window functions? (I am zero with SQL, still playing around).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a shorter version

```
with grp as (
    SELECT t.dateA, SUM(t.cnt) AS countA
    FROM  session,
    LATERAL (
       select DATE(created_at) AS dateA, 1 as cnt
       union all
       select DATE(DATE(created_at)+1), 0 as cnt
       ) t
    GROUP BY dateA
)
select t1.dateA as date, IFNULL(t1.countA-t2.countA, t1.countA) as delta 
from grp t1
left join grp t2 on DATE(t2.dateA + 1) = t1.dateA
order by t1.dateA
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3462a3530c8864a32241628297ef6137)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time. I just started with SQL, so might not able to debug much on my own ATM, but I got this error while running this.
`DDL and DML statements are not allowed in the query panel for MySQL; only SELECT statements are allowed. Put DDL and DML in the schema panel.`. A fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f5fd26/63

Comment: @SubhenduKundu, added the fiddle.